# All possible sequences of given sets of characters

Tags: r, string, sequence, tidyr

I have the following string:

```
'[ABC][abcd][XYZ]'
```

I want to generate all possible strings where the first character is A, B, or C, the second character is a, b, c, or d, and the third character is X, Y, or Z.

Example: AcX, BaZ, etc.

How to do this, preferably within Tidyverse?

Answer (score 7):

First `splitstr` the string appropriately to get a list, then using `expand.grid` and `paste0` with `do.call` .

```
el(strsplit('[ABC][abcd][XYZ]', '[\\[|\\]]', perl=TRUE)) |>
  {\(x) x[x != '']}() |>
  sapply(strsplit, '') |>
  do.call(what=expand.grid) |>
  do.call(what=paste0)
# [1] "AaX" "BaX" "CaX" "AbX" "BbX" "CbX" "AcX" "BcX" "CcX" "AdX" "BdX" "CdX" "AaY" "BaY" "CaY" "AbY" "BbY" "CbY" "AcY" "BcY"
# [21] "CcY" "AdY" "BdY" "CdY" "AaZ" "BaZ" "CaZ" "AbZ" "BbZ" "CbZ" "AcZ" "BcZ" "CcZ" "AdZ" "BdZ" "CdZ"
```

Answer (score 6):

A `stringr` solution:

```r
library(stringr)
str_extract_all(x,"(?<=\\[).+?(?=\\])", simplify = TRUE) |>
  str_split("") |>
  expand.grid() |>
  do.call(what = paste0)

# [1] "AaX" "BaX" "CaX" "AbX" "BbX" "CbX" "AcX" "BcX" "CcX" "AdX" "BdX" "CdX" "AaY" "BaY" "CaY" "AbY" "BbY" "CbY" "AcY" "BcY"
#[21] "CcY" "AdY" "BdY" "CdY" "AaZ" "BaZ" "CaZ" "AbZ" "BbZ" "CbZ" "AcZ" "BcZ" "CcZ" "AdZ" "BdZ" "CdZ"
```

This also works, using `interaction`:

```r
library(stringr)
str_extract_all(x,"(?<=\\[).+?(?=\\])", simplify = TRUE) |>
  str_split("") |>
  interaction(sep = "") |> levels()

# [1] "AaX" "BaX" "CaX" "AbX" "BbX" "CbX" "AcX" "BcX" "CcX" "AdX" "BdX" "CdX" "AaY" "BaY" "CaY" "AbY" "BbY" "CbY" "AcY" "BcY"
#[21] "CcY" "AdY" "BdY" "CdY" "AaZ" "BaZ" "CaZ" "AbZ" "BbZ" "CbZ" "AcZ" "BcZ" "CcZ" "AdZ" "BdZ" "CdZ"
```